# Does Angular $watch on an object include its prototype members?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have created a tree structure in Javascript that, unfortunately, contains circular references. (Objects have an array of children, but the children need references to the parent for deletion purposes.)

Due to the tree structure, I'm using an angular deep watch to detect any changes to the tree. (This avoids watching every node of the tree.) However, the circular references cause problems with the Angular $watch construct. I don't see a way to deal with the parent/child issue without having references to the parents, due to some design requirements of my application.

One thing I've considered is storing the link to the parent as a prototype. My question - does Angular deep $watch look at the prototype members of a custom object? Is there a setting for this somewhere?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another possible solution:  The angular deep object compare ignores functions and fields starting with $.

http://docs.angularjs.org/api/angular.equals

So obviously angular uses $ to store its own metadata, but you should be good with something like obj.$my_parent.   Or you could just assign everything with a function... obj.parent = function () { return other_obj; }

Comment: Using the `$` didn't work as I'd hoped, for various reasons, but using a function worked. I had to bite the bullet and create a class instead of using a regular object, which is what I needed to do anyway....I was just hoping for a quick workaround in anticipation of a later refactor.